# Debugging maven tests with netbeans?

Tags: java, maven-2, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, surefire

I'm trying to debug maven tests in NetBeans 6.9.1. Does anyone know how to go about doing this? The reason I ask is because if I run my tests using Maven, they all pass. However, if I debug my tests using NetBeans (right click test class -> Debug Test File) my tests fail because I have Surefire set up to handle my tests, and NetBeans seems to use its own test runner. I noticed that Surefire has a debug option, but how would you go about using that with NetBeans, i.e. have it stop on your breakpoints in NetBeans?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How do you start your tests in NetBeans? And which error occurs?

Comment: In NetBeans I can run my tests with maven by right clicking on the project and selecting Test. However if I right click on a file and select Debug Test File, it doesn't seem to use Maven to run the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very sure about that:

But you may try it with...

pom.xml

---

```
<project>
 ...
 <!-- <scope>test</scope> --> <!-- Jus comment out this line and try it -->
 ...
```

-Saligh

Comment: I've never thought of this, however it might work because I do have some artifacts marked with a <test> scope and the netbeans test runner probably doesn't read them. I'll try this when I get a chance. Thanks!